# Difference between" Get Lastest " and "Get Specific" version in TFS?

Tags: .net, tfs

I'm new in TFS and gone through keywords like `Get Latest Version` and `Get Specific Version`.

Latest  ~ Will copy server files into local
Specific ~ will compare for any changes and if not it will be same as before

I'm not sure of what i'm thinking about this two is correct..

Could someone answer what is exact differnce of both?

Comment: you should have a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141525/why-doesnt-tfs-get-latest-get-the-latest)

Comment: But, **Get Specific** gets the the files for a specific version (changeset) and **Get Latest** will get the files by the latest version with some dirty little secrets mentioned in the link above.

Comment: Welcome to [so], we all have to start somewhere. In future please do a google search before asking such trivial questions. Good luck!

Comment: @BeytanKurt That question is just chocked full of bad assumptions, misunderstandings and outright insanity.  There are good resources on TFVC, that question is not even close to being one of them.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I'd like to read if you can share links to these resources, don't know what you mean by TFVC, I assume it is Team Foundation Version Control

Comment: @BeytanKurt Absolutely, I provided some details as an answer to that question.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29921613/729881

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get Latest means get the Last that is Checked In (by anyone). With Get Specific Version you can get specific by user time changeset or just description.

**Edit:**

The main difference is that using **Get Specific** shows a dropdownlist allowing you to get a historical version using a variety of "time-stamped changesets".

For example you may choose to Get Specific Version by *Label*.

Comment: Exactly.  "Get Latest" is just a proper subset of "Get Specific".  It is equivalent to "Get Specific" by version "Latest".  The "Get Specific" dialog just gives you more knobs to turn.