# TFS: Force update does not work

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

My objective is to get the files in the TFS into my local computer.
The computer I am using has previously been used by someone else, which I assume is the root of my problem.

I connect to the server, and in Source Control Explorer I find the folder that I want to download. I right click it, and a popup with the following pops up:

```
Source Control Explorer
All files are up to date.
No files were updated because the requested file versions were previously downloaded.
To force an update, use the "Get Specific Version" command with the "Overwrite all..." option checked.
```

Ok, so I do this, as is also suggested in [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141525/why-doesnt-tfs-get-latest-get-the-latest). It gives exactly the same result. I tried all different combinations of checking and unchecking the boxes.

I also tried to delete the workspace, and cleared the caches for Visual Studio and Team Foundation.

What should I do?

Comment: so you trid "get specific version" type: latest and checked the 2 checkboxes "overwrite writable files" and "overwrite all files even if the local ..."

Comment: @lordkain , yes I did.

Comment: you tried a restart computer (what version vs do you have)

Comment: Yes, I have. I use Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: maybe somthing todo with workspace name ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784296/how-to-remove-a-tfs-workspace-mapping

Comment: I have tried all different suggestions in that thread :P Really frustrating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.
I was not yet added to my team on the Team Foundation site.
Wierd that I could still see all the code.

Comment: Yep, this worked for me as well.  It would give me the same misleading error message as it did for you.  It wouldn't let me see any code, just the directory structure in TFS.  When I tried to open a file from within the source control explorer, it would give me a better error message - "you don't have the read permissions" or something of that nature.  We migrated domains recently and I had some username issues, so i added my new username to the TFS admin portal and all was good again.