# Get Latest Version twice (multiple times)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

i have a strange behaviour in my Visual Studio 2015 when i hit *Get latest version*.

Sometimes i need to do this twice to be sure that the latest version is fetched.
I look at the output window when it says `All files are up to date.` everything is fine.

Is this normal?

Comment: Is it possible that a *Resolve Conflicts* dialog is opening in a tab that is not visible in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to do this. When you do a get latest option in VS. You can do this in source control explorer. Right click the file and get latest.

After doing this, you just need to check a column of source control explorer which called "**Latest**", the value should change from "**No**" to "**Yes**".

**Update Screenshot**

[image]

@D.Konosov Well, if so you still don't need to *pay too much attention* for this. Since even though  you do the **get latest**. It's still not "the really latest”  in many cases. More details for your reference  [Why doesn't TFS get latest get the latest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141525/why-doesnt-tfs-get-latest-get-the-latest)

And during the time from your working on to checking in source control. Some others of your team very likely **checked in another version**. You still have to **resolve conflicts** for your code.

In my opinion, **you don't have to do this.** Every morning, when you start working, do the "get latest" once, and after you fininshd the work on it. Check in it in TFS. You may have to resolve conflicts during the check in option.

Certainly, if you insist on keeping this behavior, keep it. After all, it's nothing business.

Comment: Add related screenshot, before you getting latest for the `zero1.sln` file the status of "**Latest**" should be the same with `TestDoc.txt` **No**. After you getting latest, it will change to **Yes**.

Comment: I guess @D.Konosov is talking about hitting `Get Latest Version (Recursive)` from the context menu in an opened solution. You cannot be serious to have a look at the field Latest=Yes at every file...?!

Comment: @D.Konosov Well, if so you still don't need to pay too much attention for this. Since even though  you do the get latest. It's still not the really latest  in many cases. And during the time from working to checking in source control. Some others of your team very likely checked in another version. You still have to resolve conflicts for your code. More details for  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141525/why-doesnt-tfs-get-latest-get-the-latest . Details see my update answer.